# update or downgrade .csproj file after nuget restore packages from packages.config

Tags: nuget-package, azure-pipelines, csproj

I have many VSTS builds which has reference to one nuget package. Depending on primiary build we have to sometimes to upgrade/downgrade nuget package in VSTS build. We are doing this by copying packages.config with proper version, then we use nuget restore. My problem is that after upgrade/downgrade of nuget package .csproj file still have old version od package reference, so when build starts it still try to search for old reference from .csproj file and build fails.

I there any way to change .csproj file after nuget restore?

Comment: I recommend looking into using `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config` which allows you to specify the dependencies in the csproj or imported files - with some logic you can even make the version replaceable easily. are you on VS 2017 already? what kind of projects are those?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to update the `.csproj` during the build. You should **change the `.csproj` locally and then build in VSTS**.

Except the way manually changed the .csproj file, there has an easier way to change package versions correspondingly in `.csproj`. Execute below command in **Package Manager Console** window:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

So the workflow to use upgrade/downgrade nuget package version as below:

1. Change the versions in `package.config` file.
2. Run the command `update-package -reinstall` in in Package Manager Console window.
3. Commit and push/checkin the changes to remote repo.
4. Build your project in VSTS with the upgrade/downgrade nuget package version reference.